# Regex to remove \" from a Groovy GString?

Tags: regex, json, grails, groovy

I'm trying to parse a JSON using Grails, to test the parser I Wrote an unit test and put my input JSON in a GString that looks something like this:

```
"""{"Information":"Some data here \"stuff\" some more.","AnswerToEverything":42,"Other":71,"Name":"Joe Doe"}"""
```

The \"stuff\" is causing the parser to break.

I tried using `String.replace(/\\"/, "")` and a few other combinations to remove the \" but it either does nothing or removes all the quotes from the string.
[This post](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t129344-string-replaceall-string-regex-string-replacement-question.html) tells me that I need to use 5 slashes: `\\\\\"` to get it to work in Java but it isn't working in Groovy.

Edit: This test should pass for it to work:

```
str = """foo \"foobar\" bar"""
assert  str.replace("""\\\"""", "")  == "foo foobar bar"
```

With the above regex it fails.

Any tips?

Comment: The post you linked to actually seems to indicate you need 5 total slashes: "you need four backslashes to get one into the output, and one more to
escape the double-quote"

Comment: 5 slashes don't work either (or anything from 1 to 6, tested just to make sure). Corrected the mistake, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, regexps written with as `/regexp/` seem to have trouble with escaped backslashes. You can write the regexp with the `"""` construct like so:

```
str = "\\\""
assert str[0] == "\\"
assert str[1] == "\""

assert str =~ """\\\""""
assert str.replace("""\\\"""", "") == ""
```

EDIT: The JSON in the original post doesn't contain any literal backslashes.  You still need to escape literal backslashes even in `"""strings"""`.  I'm guessing you want to escape those, like in `json2` below:

```
json1 = """{"Information":"Some data here \"stuff\" some more.","AnswerToEverything":42,"Other":71,"Name":"Joe Doe"}"""
json2 = """{"Information":"Some data here \\"stuff\\" some more.","AnswerToEverything":42,"Other":71,"Name":"Joe Doe"}"""
assert !json1.contains("\\")
assert json2.contains("\\")
assert json2.replace("""\\\"""", "replacement").contains("replacement")
```

Comment: Didn't work, I used your code to create a simple test, the code is in the original question (formatting doesn't work on comments).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I actually have no control of the contents of the input JSON, the string I'm getting is like your 'json1' example, I'm trying to remove the \" so the JSON parser works. To escape the slashes ( \\" ) I would have to edit the input manually, which I can't, or figure out a way to detect the \" in a regex, so I could replace it by \\" or just remove it.